# Running multiple animations in Windows Store App

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

The following code is was originally part of a WPF app that I'm converting over to WinRT; however, when trying to run the animations, they appear to be mutually exclusive (that is, they both work, but only one at a time - whereas in WPF I could run them together):

```
    private void SpinAndDisappear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement obj = (UIElement)SpinAndDisappear;

        obj.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

        var story = new Storyboard();

        var xAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
        var yAnim = new DoubleAnimation();            

        xAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        yAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);            

        xAnim.To = 0;
        yAnim.To = 0;

        story.Children.Add(xAnim);
        story.Children.Add(yAnim);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnim, obj);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(yAnim, obj);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnim, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnim, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)");

        story.Begin();

        SpinAnimation(); // If commented out, the button changes size, 
                         // and  if not, it spins, but not both
    }

    void SpinAnimation()
    {
        UIElement obj = (UIElement)SpinAndDisappear;

        obj.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform();
        var storySpin = new Storyboard();
        var spinAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
        spinAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        spinAnim.From = 0;
        spinAnim.To = 360;
        storySpin.Children.Add(spinAnim);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(spinAnim, obj);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(spinAnim, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTranform.Angle)");

        storySpin.Begin();
    }
```

So my question is: how to do both simultaneously in WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one Storyboard can run on a single element in WinRT/XAML. If you need to run two of them independently from each other - the easiest way to do it is to have two elements and target separate elements. In your case you could have a parent `Grid` with a `ScaleTransform` and a child control with a `RotateTransform`. Then you would call `Storyboard.SetTarget()` to target the separate transforms in separate storyboards and everything should just work.